# Error while loading icons on homepage- wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, fonts

I recently installed a plugin for my blog. The social media and search icons appear as square box only on home page of the website and on rest of the pages, it works fine. Below are the logs from console while loading homepage.

Screenshot (home): http://prntscr.com/en1i67
Screenshot (other pages):http://prntscr.com/en1ih9

> Access to Font at 'link' from origin 'link' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'link' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: your fonts get from same server?, your font location may be different server.

Solution: get your font from same server location

Comment: If your assets loads from another server then you need [enable cross-origin resource sharing](https://enable-cors.org/). Can you share the url? Hard to debug otherwise.